# unrecognized token: "'"Alliance Française""

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin

Trying to query a sqlite database table using the following query:

```
select * from contact where FullName='Alliance Française'
```

I am getting the following error:

```
unrecognized token: "'Alliance Française"

Stack Trace:
  at SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLiteApiAndroid.Prepare2     (SQLite.Net.Interop.IDbHandle db, System.String query) [0x00037] in  <8dbf6ff85082469fb9d4dfaa9eae6b69>:0 
  at SQLite.Net.SQLiteCommand.Prepare () [0x0001c] in <8f2bb39aeff94a30a8628064be9c7efe>:0 
  at SQLite.Net.SQLiteCommand+<ExecuteDeferredQuery>d__15`1[T].MoveNext () [0x0003f] in <8f2bb39aeff94a30a8628064be9c7efe>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T]..ctor (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] collection) [0x0008b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs:99 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs:861 
  at SQLite.Net.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteQuery[T] () [0x0001c] in <8f2bb39aeff94a30a8628064be9c7efe>:0 
  at SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection.Query[T] (System.String query, System.Object[] args) [0x00008] in <8f2bb39aeff94a30a8628064be9c7efe>:0 
  at Prototype.Core.CRUDRepository`1[T].GetByQuery (System.String query, SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection dbConnection) [0x00002] in C:\C# Projects\Apps Dev\Your Messengar App\ServerApps\Prototype\MessagePrototype\Prototype.Core\CRUDRepository.cs:163
```

Not sure how to proceed.

Regards,

Will

Comment: In the error it seems you missed a simple quote at the end of the second word => "'Alliance Française"

Comment: Look at the original query, non is missing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using
     dbConnection.Query(query, selectionArgs)